# Apache service is up and running but not in web browser

Tags: server, apache2

I have migrated my Ubuntu server to AWS EC2 instance.
The problem is Apache service is up and running but when I type "server-IP/phppage.php" nothing is displayed. After a while "The connection has timed out" error is displayed. Port 80 is listening and I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

```
yello-pc123:~$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      912/apache2         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20739    809/python3          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20380    1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18058    809/python3          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     14606    480/lvmetad          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18059    1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20269    803/systemd-logind   
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    20150    803/systemd-logind   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17898    803/systemd-logind
```

Since I dont have GUI access to server I do `$curl localhost` which gives

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Apache2 Debian Default Page: It works</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Edit: I have changed the listen directive to `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`, but still no success. 
New output of `$sudo netstat -anp | grep 80` is

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10236/apache2       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20739    809/python3          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20380    1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18058    809/python3          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     14606    480/lvmetad          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18059    1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20269    803/systemd-logind   
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    20150    803/systemd-logind   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17898    803/systemd-logind
```

Edit

```
yello-pc123:~$ sudo cat /var/log/apache2/error.log 
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/pdo_sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Sun May 10 06:25:01.830025 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2247] AH00163: Apache/2.4.43 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 10 06:25:01.830043 2020] [core:notice] [pid 2247] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun May 10 11:24:34.076951 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2247] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/pdo_sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Sun May 10 11:25:16.357649 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 895] AH00163: Apache/2.4.43 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 10 11:25:16.357720 2020] [core:notice] [pid 895] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun May 10 11:39:58.714752 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 895] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/pdo_sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Sun May 10 11:39:58.845545 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1679] AH00163: Apache/2.4.43 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 10 11:39:58.845609 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1679] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: What does it display when you type "server-IP/phpinfo.php" in the browser's address line?

Comment: Also try using 127.0.0.1 as the server IP and see if it responds using that IP address.  If that doesn't work, try " ping -c1 127.0.0.1 " and see if it has packet loss.

Comment: When I enter server-IP/phphinfo.page it keeps on loading and after a while a message is displayed that says "The connection has timed out"

Comment: Your `netstat` output is ***not*** showing that apache is running. Verify that it is in fact running, and check all logs.

Comment: `$ sudo service apache2 status` , Its giving message that its `active (running)`. What else to check

Comment: @vidarlo `$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 80` first line is 
`tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      5601/apache2`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it - anyway; it's only listening on IPv6, not IPv4. This is probably why it works when you `curl localhost` as per previous edits.

Comment: @vidarlo thanks for reply. any guide on how to start troubleshooting the apache, with info I have provided. can you tell me wt output should be for correct netstat?

Comment: @vidarlo I have changed the listen directive to `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`, I have also posted new output of $sudo netstat -anp | grep 80 . Still no success.

Comment: @StephenDaddona  $ ping -c1 127.0.0.1 is working fine it says " 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms". – bilaljan321 12 hours ago

Comment: Have you tried to stop and restart apache?  { sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart }   The stuff between the curly braces is supposed to be code but I don't know how to enter code.  Duh.

Comment: I'm shooting in the dark here, but does this command return anything?  <pre><code> sudo grep timed /var/log/apache2/error.log </code></pre>  I tried to show this as code but I don't know how yet.

Comment: @StephenDaddona I have issued this enormous times `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. The `sudo grep timed /var/log/apache2/error.log` return nothing. I have posted complete `/var/log/apache2/error.log` in above post.

Comment: It looks to me like [ /usr/lib/php/20131226/*.so ] either does not exist or, perhaps, that the privileges on those files is not allowing PHP (or Apache?) to see them.  I wish I knew more, but I'm an amateur at this, myself.  I'm flagging a guru to see if I can attract his attention to this question.  Hey, @Jos, you're really good at Ubuntu.  Do you have an idea what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer after three days of struggle.
I am leaving answer for future reference,if anyone else is facing same problem he may use this.
since everything at localhost is working fine. The problem is that since VM is on EC2 instance and AWS by default block HTTP traffic coming on port 80. So you have to add inbound rule for incoming traffic in security group. This link explain the details https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/

Comment: Wow!  That is over my head.  I'm so glad you were able to resolve this problem and even answer the question yourself.  I'm upvoting your answer.  You deserve the reputation!  Congratulations!